# TypeScript properties returning a promise - Get/Set accessors must have the same type

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Why does TypeScript enforce Get/Set accessors to have the same type?
Let's say I want to have a property which returns a promise.

```
module App {
    export interface MyInterface {
        foo: ng.IPromise<IStuff>;
    }

    export interface IStuff {
        bar: string;
        baz: number;
    }

    class MyClass implements MyInterface {
        private _fooDeferred: ng.IDeferred<IStuff>;

        constructor(private $q: ng.IQService) {
            this._fooDeferred = this.$q.defer();
        }

        get foo(): ng.IPromise<IStuff> {
            return this._fooDeferred.promise;
        }

        set foo(value: IStuff) {
            this._fooDeferred.resolve(value);
        }
    }
}
```

**'Get' and 'Set' accessor must have the same type** will be the error message coming from TypeScript.

The fix would be to type the accessors to **any**, but then we are losing the advantages of static typing, and might as well just write JS.

```
        get foo(): any {
            return this._fooDeferred.promise;
        }

        set foo(value: any) {
            this._fooDeferred.resolve(value);
        }
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to have a class where properties have different types when read vs written to? This seems like an abuse of getters/setters.

Comment: Ryan, that is my question. How else would you have a property which returns a promise? Steve Fenton's answer below appears reasonable.

Comment: Since a resolved promise shouldn't be resolved multiple times, even with Steve Fenton's implementation you will need to guard against setting the property more than once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect opportunity to use a union type (TypeScript 1.4 or above) - example taken from [this blog post](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201502/Blog/Union-Types-Ease-Getters-and-Setters/):

```
type StringPromise = string | ng.IPromise<string>;

module App {
    export interface MyInterface {
        foo: ng.IPromise<string>;
    }

    class MyClass implements MyInterface {
        private _fooDeferred: ng.IDeferred<string>;

        constructor(private $q: ng.IQService) {
            this._fooDeferred = this.$q.defer();
        }

        get foo(): StringPromise {
            return this._fooDeferred.promise;
        }

        set foo(value: StringPromise) {
            this._fooDeferred.resolve(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- You will need to use type guards when you want to use a specific type from the union type
- You may need to use type assertions in some cases

## Type Guard

Here is an example of a type guard

```
if (typeof value === 'string') {
    // the type of value inside this if statement is
    // string, rather than StringPromise
} else {
    // the type of value inside this else statement is
    // ng.IPromise<string>, rather than StringPromise
}
```

## Type Assertion

If needed, you can assert types like this:

```
var prom = <string> value;
```

Comment: One complication with the type guards/assertions is if the type is an interface instead of a primitive. I'll update my question to reflect that.